# MS Graph API Propagating event metadata to invites

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using MS graph API to create an event in a user's outlook calendar. This event has attendees and contains some metadata that I added. When the invites are created for the attendees, the graph API calls my webhook for the newly created events for the attendees. However, those invites do not contain the metadata.

Is there a way to have the metadata in the initial event propagated to all other invites?
If not, is there a property that I can use that is copied over on to all invites??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the above scenario, you can use either extended properties or open extensions. Let me add few additional info about them.

- (1) Extended properties - Use extended properties only if you need to access custom data for Outlook MAPI properties that are not already exposed in the [Microsoft Graph API metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/index.md?view=graph-rest-1.0)
- (2) Open extensions - In most common scenarios, you should be able to use open extensions - also known as [openTypeExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/opentypeextension?view=graph-rest-1.0), formerly known as Office 365 data extensions - to store and access custom data for resource instances in a user's mailbox;

So check it out and see which suits your scenario. For more info, please [refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/extended-properties-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0).